# Jquery Datatable missaligned headers while using scroll property

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a requirement as Datatable with fixed headers, while using scroll property i was loosing the headers width respective to the td tags,i can fix this issue by removing scroll property but i want  a better solution to fix this issue .I have already googled many of them suggested Columnadjusting function but it is not working in IE and Edge browsers.I thinking that some body will help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is the sample code what  i have used in my project.

```
 var menulst1=  $('#tbmenulist').DataTable({
            scrollY: '415px',
            scrollCollapse: true,
            bFilter: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            destroy:true,
            )};
```